# Pseudo elements styling in lightning component

Tags: lightning, css, style, lightningstylesheets

I have a html table defined in my lightning component.

I want to change the CSS for the pseudo elements --> `::Before` and `::after`.

Similar to this screenshot, 
I would like to add the below line with

```
box-sizing : content-box;
```

[image: Table box-sizing issue]

How can i change the above screenshot box-sizing value as content-box in lightning styles.

Comment: did you ever found the solution?